# why does bsd grep behave this way

Tags: grep, bsd

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

When using bsd grep with the `-o` option and a multiline search pattern I get results seemingly printed twice.  This behavior cannot be reproduced with GNU grep.

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -o $'foo\nfoo'
foo
foo
foo
foo
$ echo foo | grep -o foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -o foo
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | grep -o $'foo\nfoo'
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep $'foo\nfoo'
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -co $'foo\nfoo'
2
```

Is this a bug or is there some other explanation for this?

EDIT:

It seems like the multiline strings are just treated as individual search patterns however the behavior is still different than when using extended regex

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -o $'foo\nbaz\nfoo'
foo
foo
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -Eo 'foo|baz|foo'
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -o -e foo -e foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -e foo -e foo
foo
foo
$ printf '%s\n' foo foo bar bar | grep -o -e foo -e foo -e foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: Is it really treated as a multiline search pattern - or is it matching a each line as a separate pattern? What happens with `... | grep -o $'foo\nbaz\nfoo'` for example

Comment: @steeldriver ah, looks like it is treating each line as a separate pattern.  But still odd that it prints them twice.

Comment: ... indeed - especially as the documentation says *"selecting lines that match one or more patterns"*, which seems to imply de-duplication. Does `grep -o -e foo -e foo` do the same?

Comment: Does `echo foo | grep -o $'foo\nfoo\nfoo'` print the match 3 times?

Comment: Which shell are you using and what does it think you mean by `$'foo\nbaz\nfoo'`?

Comment: To match multiple lines with grep you MUST use GNU grep for `-z` to enable reading NUL-separated blocks of input instead of newline separated, otherwise you're reading 1 line at a time and trying to match 2 lines against that 1 line which obviously cant possibly match.